# How to have one person look tall and another look small in one image?

Tags: perspective, special-effects

When one of my friends showed me a picture, I was amazed on how it was done.  The picture shows two people standing on the ground, but one of the people appears to be much taller and bigger than a normal human being.  How was this picture taken?

Comment: It would be very helpful to have a link to the picture you are referring to, or at least to a similar picture.

Comment: Having just watched the Fellowship of the Ring there's an interesting point where this is used when Gandalf and Frodo are sitting in the wagon talking. It's not done with CGI but with perspective and is explained somewhere in the 'making of' sequences.

Comment: Here's how it was done: http://bananascoop.com/2012/09/11/lord-of-the-rings-middle-earth-mysteries/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the technique you are referring to is [Forced Perspective](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forced_perspective)

There is a guide here on how to achieve some interesting shots

http://www.brighthub.com/multimedia/photography/reviews/127109.aspx

The bottom line is you need to have physical distance between subject one and subject two - this technique success depends on loads of factors - e.g. if its done with the right subjects and right setup - It has to look unforced.

I like the Eiffel tower example in the guide but the hand shake one would have been good if the distant subject was well lit.

As a further note on cam settings - your going to want a small aperture (higher than f/8) to capture sufficient detail in the foreground and background

Plan your shot!